# Can I change my TokenValidationParameters ( issuer and audience) dynamically in AddJwtBearer while adding authentication for my web app

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, authorization, .net-7.0

[image: Code]
Can I add dynamic issuer and audiences in JWT token generation?
Can I achieve it using PostConfigure method?

A workaround using PostConfigure will be handy or any other approach

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the delegate's AudienceValidator and IssuerValidator which are done to add custom authentication and are called for validating token as per each request.

[image: ValidateAudience]

Then you can create a ValidateAudience with the defined parameters and that will do your work.

[image]